# Script will run on Laptop but not Desktop

Tags: vbscript, windows-7-x64, outlook-2010

I have a very basic script and a .Bat file to execute it.

The Script is as follows ...

```
Dim oOL
Set oOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
oOL.Quit
```

The Batch file as follows on the Laptop ...

```
@echo off
cscript "D:\Outlook\CloseOutlook.VBS"
:EXIT
```

... and as follows on the Desktop ...

```
@echo off
cscript "O:\CloseOutlook.VBS"
:EXIT
```

The D: drive on the Laptop and the O: drive on the Desktop are both local drives to that machine, they are not network drives. Both machines are running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and Outlook 2010 Professional Plus 32-bit.

However, whilst it runs just fine on the Laptop, the script doesn't close Outlook on the Desktop. UAC is set to Never Notify on both machines.

Any suggestions as to why this is working on one machine and not the other ?!?

Comment: Do you get an error output in the command window when outlook doesn't close?

Comment: No that I've noticed, but it closes pretty quickly, can I stop it from closing, would taking the :EXIT line off do that ?

Comment: You can add [`PAUSE`](http://ss64.com/nt/pause.html) to the batch to wait for a key to close the window.

Comment: I will try that right now ...

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, it just says "Press any key to continue..."

Comment: ... but, I ran it once in Admin Mode and it worked, it is now working all the time but NOT in Admin mode, how bizarre !!!

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion make sure it's running in an elevated command window. Glad it's working for you now.

Comment: Fingers crossed it keeps working :-) !!! Thanks for your help ...